# What cocktails would be good mixed with Nanaimo Bar Cream?

Tags: recommendations, pairing, cocktails, liqueur

An Ontario-based whisky distillery has created a new “Nanaimo Bar Cream” liqueur which is reportedly “flying off shelves” across the country. Here in BC liqueur has just arrived on the shelves.

I would like to serve it in a cocktail at our Christmas dinner. My father-in-law is from Nanaimo, BC.

> Forty Creek Whisky first launched its new Nanaimo Bar-flavoured liqueur locally in September before expanding it across the country in October. Already, inventory in B.C. is hard to find.
>
> The flavours include hints of wafer, coconut, chocolate and rich custard, says Allard.
>
> Nanaimo Bar Cream liqueur is available at 100 BC Liquor Stores and approximately 200 private liquor stores in the province, according to Forty Creek.
>
> Given the success of the product, the distillery hopes to make the dessert liqueur a permanent addition to its portfolio. - [Canadian whisky distillery launches Nanaimo Bar liqueur](https://vancouverisland.ctvnews.ca/canadian-whisky-distillery-launches-nanaimo-bar-liqueur-1.5149015)

Although it may be served straight and neat, I would like to serve it in a cocktail. Any recommendations would be welcome.

Also any food pairings recommendations would be greatly appreciated also, avoiding the obvious one: [**Nanaimo Bar**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanaimo_bar)

[image: FORTY CREEK - NANAIMO BAR CREAM]

[FORTY CREEK - NANAIMO BAR CREAM](https://www.bcliquorstores.com/product/74755)

Comment: I don't think dessert liqueurs are "paired" with food. Just serve with whatever you are serving with dessert.

Comment: You might look at existing suggestions for Baileys Irish Cream to see if any of them sound appropriate. They aren't the same thing, but I imagine that both are sweet, creamy, and have a strong flavour of coffee or chocolate.

Comment: What about an [_affogato_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affogato) with some mild-taste icecream? :)

Comment: @MattAllegro if you would like to make an answer out of that I would up vote it and possibly more.

Comment: “Nanaimo Bar Cream”  Sounds like a women's skin care product. *Before you go out for a night on the town, make sure you shave your legs with “Nanaimo Bar Cream”*

Comment: @AlaskaMan That does not sound like a bad thing at all. I might need some mind bleach now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a liqueur really pairs with food other than a sweet dessert. Given that, I'd "pair" Nanaimo Bar Cream liqueur with [German chocolate cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_chocolate_cake). German chocolate cake confusingly has nothing to do with Germany. Alternatively perhaps [Boston cream pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_cream_pie) which actually does have something to do with Boston.

Answer (score 2):

One idea may be to make an [*affogato*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affogato) with the liquor poured on a mild-taste ice cream portion, for example cream (*fior di latte*) or custard ice cream.

> An affogato or more traditionally known as "affogato al caffe" (Italian for "drowned") is an Italian coffee-based dessert. It usually takes the form of a scoop of fior di latte or vanilla gelato or ice cream topped or "drowned" with a shot of hot espresso. Some variations also include a shot of amaretto, Bicerin, Kahlua, or other liqueur.
>
> **Variety of Affogato**
>
> Though restaurants and cafes in Italy categorize the affogato as a dessert, some restaurants and cafes outside of Italy categorize it as a beverage. Whether a dessert or beverage, restaurants and cafes usually serve the affogato in a tall narrowing glass, allowing the fior di latte, vanilla gelato, or ice cream melt and combine with espresso into the hollowed space in the bottom of the glass. Occasionally, coconut, berries, honeycomb and multiple flavors of ice cream are added. A biscotti or cookie can also be served and enjoyed along side this beverage. Affogatos are often enjoyed as a post-meal coffee dessert combo eaten and or drank with a spoon or straw.
>
> While the recipe of the affogato is more or less standard in Italy, consisting of a scoop of vanilla gelato topped with a shot of espresso, variations exist in European and American restaurants.
>
> In French, it is known as "gelato al fior di latte" with the translation to English "flower of milk". Typically the ingredients in the ice cream includes dairy, starch, and sugar. It is popular in countries where they dress it with chocolate syrup, cantuccini, or biscotti to provide extra flavors.

---

Now one proper recipe! For four cups.

- 4 egg yolks
- 4 spoons of sugar
- 2 spoons of flour
- 2 spoons of potato starch
- 700 ml of milk
- 100 ml of Nanaimo Bar Cream
- cocoa powder

Meanwhile milk gets to boiling temperature in a pan, beat properly the yolks with the sugar, then add the flour, the starch and stir and mix well. Then add the Nanaimo Bar Cream to the mixture. Pour the mixture in the milk pan on low heat and carry on stirring until the cream get dense.

Pour into four cups and cool at room temperature first, then in the fridge. When cooled, sprinkle cocoa and serve!

Comment: @KenGraham updated...it's turning to a very yummy thing :)

Answer (score 1):

**What cocktails would be good mixed with Nanaimo Bar Cream?**

Taking up the suggestion in the comments by [Ray Butterworth](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/11599/ray-butterworth), I looked it up and found [this](https://winecocktails.wordpress.com/tag/baileys/). It sounded quite interesting.

Seeing that some [wines](https://www.delipair.com/wines/nanaimo-bars-recipe-yummly/) pair well with the actual Nanaimo Bars, one could envision using the recipe for a cocktail that follows with a German Riesling, Red Cabernet Sauvignon or a White Sauvignon Blanc:

> Since Chocolate goes well with wine and Baileys and Hot Chocolate is a popular drink, we thought this had to work.  We were a little nervous at first but it actually shocked us and turned out to taste really good.
>
> **Ingredients:**
>
> - 5 oz Baileys
> - 5 oz Port or a Heavy Red Wine
> - 5 oz Hot Chocolate
> - Garnish with Whipped Cream
>
> **Recipe:**
>
> First heat up the hot chocolate.  Next pour the Baileys into the cup.  Then pour the wine into the cup.  Top off cup with hot chocolate.  Stir the drink until mixed.  Do not shake.  Garnish drink with Whipped Cream.
>
> - 5 oz Baileys
> - 5 oz Port or a Heavy Red Wine
> - 5 oz Hot Chocolate
> - Garnish with Whipped Cream
>
> **Recipe:**
>
> First heat up the hot chocolate.  Next pour the Baileys into the cup.  Then pour the wine into the cup.  Top off cup with hot chocolate.  Stir the drink until mixed.  Do not shake.  Garnish drink with Whipped Cream.
>
> **Source:** [Luck of the Irish Red Port Cocktail](https://winecocktails.wordpress.com/tag/baileys/)